# How to handle long text in InputDecoration->labelText in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a TextFormField in Flutter setup, like this:

```
new TextFormField (
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
    labelText: questionString,
    labelStyle: new TextStyle(
      fontSize: 18.0,
      color: new Color(0xFF18776A),
    )
),
```

This generates the following screenshot:

[image: TextFormField with labelText]

The text is cutting at the end automatically because is too long. Is there a way to adjust the font size to fit the screen or make labelText expand to two lines?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for adding to an old question, but just learning flutter myself and stumbled into a similar issue.

My workaround was to use hintText instead of labelText, and explicitly adding \n line breaks to it.

Something like

```
String questionString = 'This sample is very \n very very very long'
new TextFormField (
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
    hintText: questionString,
    hintStyle: new TextStyle(
      fontSize: 18.0,
      color: new Color(0xFF18776A),
    ) .
```

),

I don't like this as it's essentially hard coding the screen width. But it does at least give a multi line hint text.

When I tried adding line breaks to my labelText things got quite strange with the lower lines of the labelText merging down into the actual input field. Maybe if I could work out a way to add padding in there somewhere to prevent this it would be a little better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TextFormFields](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) `maxLines` property:

```
new TextFormField ( 
    maxLines: 4,
    decoration: new InputDecoration( 
        labelText: questionString, 
        labelStyle: new TextStyle( 
            fontSize: 18.0, 
            color: new Color(0xFF18776A), 
        ) 
 ),
```

Comment: maxLines on TextFormFIeld just increases the height of the field and has no effect on the labelText

Comment: You could use hintText instead.

Comment: Tried that, hintText shows also only at the first line (if TextFormField has more than one maxLines) so the text is cutting at the end again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hintText and hintMaxLines:

```
String questionString = 'This sample is very \n very very very long'
new TextFormField (
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
    hintText: questionString,
    hintMaxLines: 2,
    hintStyle: new TextStyle(
      fontSize: 18.0,
      color: new Color(0xFF18776A),
    )
```